# Error handling (try-catch) for given asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, try-catch, control-flow

In the following code, the (toy) functions `f1` and `f2` are from a library, so that I cannot change them.

```
function f1() { // cannot change this
   var x;
   alert(x.y); // throws an error because x is undefined
}
function f2() { // cannot change this either
   setTimeout(f1, 1000); // creates an asynchronous timeout
}
```

Now I would like to catch the error:

```
try { // does not work because of the asynchronous environment
   f2();
} catch (error) {
   console.log('caught: ' + error);
}
```

But I know that this does not work, as the environment created by `setTimeout` is not the one for which the try-catch block was specified.

Is there any other possibility to catch the error?

Comment: @alfasin OP said he can't change `f1` and `f2`

Comment: @Zenoo: Then the OP is out of luck. The only way to catch errors in a function that's called asynchronously, is to add a `try/catch` block to that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding the `f1` function...

```js
// original functions -- this is all the code you can't modify
function f1() {
  throw "Oh no - an exception!";
}

function f2() {
  try {
    setTimeout(f1, 1000);
  }
  catch(e) {
    alert(e + " - this is handled in the original code");
  }
}
// end of the code you can't modify



// keep a reference to the original f1 function
var __f1 = f1;

// override the original f1 function
var f1 = function() {
  try {
    // this calls the original version of f1(), along with any parameters
    return __f1.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  catch(e) {
    alert(e + " - this is handled in your new code");
  }
};

// execute...
f2();
```

Comment: I agree with the answer, but as the OP said:  _"The functions `f1` and `f2` are from a library, so that I cannot change them."_

Comment: No? Then what is `var f1 = function() {`? You may not have access to that.

Comment: There may be another problem: What if in reality, `f2 = function() {//someStuff; setTimeout(f1, 1000); //someStuff;}`. And you do not know or have no access to someStuff. Can you overwride f2 then?

Comment: No, that would mean actually changing `f2()`.  You can do things before and after the existing methods, assuming they're publicly accessible, but you can't change the contents of the methods.  If you can give us more info maybe there are ways, but from what you've said likely not.

Comment: Would a global error handler be more suited to your needs?  That's a simple thing to do.

Comment: Well, a global error handler is not an ideal solution, but it seems that there really is no other way then. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In case the closed third-party function of interest ... here `f1` ... is accessible, a method/function modifier approach, which provides an abstraction layer of implemented functions like e.g. `afterThrowing` or `afterFinally`, comes in very handy as will be proven with the next provided example code ...

```js
// closed third party code that can not be changed.
function f1() {
  var x;

  // raises an exception because of an undefined `x`.
  alert(x.y);

  console.log('... should never bee logged.')
}
// closed third party code that can not be changed either.
function f2() {
  // invocation happens deferred/asynchronous.
   setTimeout(f1, 2000);

   console.log('... main thread finished.');
}

function handleThirdPartyInvocationException(exception) {
  const { message, stack } = exception;

  console.log(
    '... handling of following delayed third party function invocation error ...', {
      message, stack
    }
  );
}
// - reassign the accessable third party namespace/reference
//   with a modified, exception handling, version of itself.
f1 = f1.afterThrowing(handleThirdPartyInvocationException);

// - invoke third party main thread.
f2();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
function isFunction(value) {
  return (
    typeof value === 'function' &&
    typeof value.call === 'function' &&
    typeof value.apply === 'function'
  );
}
function getSanitizedTarget(value) {
  return value ?? null;
}

function afterThrowing(handler, target) {
  target = getSanitizedTarget(target);

  const proceed = this;
  return (

    isFunction(handler) &&
    isFunction(proceed) &&

    function afterThrowingType(...argumentArray) {
      const context = getSanitizedTarget(this) ?? target;

      let result;
      try {
        result = proceed.apply(context, argumentArray);

      } catch (exception) {

        result = handler.call(context, exception, argumentArray);
      }
      return result;
    }
  ) || proceed;
}
Reflect.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'afterThrowing', {
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
  value: afterThrowing,
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Remirror ... The OP might have a look at the above, late provided, answer.

Comment: Interesting solution if `f1` is accessible; a "local error handler" is probably better than a global one. Sadly, "internal" functions like `f1` are not often exported by libraries that export `f2` instead, so it won't work for that case.